# Creating an array of objects from a large unsorted object

Tags: arrays, typescript, object

I need to create an array of objects from some data in TypeScript. The data i get from an api is terribly formatted as it is just one big object.

It looks something like this.

```
KeyBinary00: null
KeyBinary01: null
KeyBinary02: null
KeyBinary03: null
KeyBinary04: null
KeyBoolean00: "deling"
KeyBoolean01: null
KeyBoolean02: null
KeyBoolean03: null
KeyBoolean04: null
KeyDateTime00: "start"
KeyDateTime01: "slutt"
KeyDateTime02: null
KeyDateTime03: null
KeyDateTime04: null
KeyInteger00: "verdi"
KeyInteger01: null
KeyInteger02: null
KeyInteger03: null
KeyInteger04: null
KeyString00: "status"
KeyString01: "beskrivelse"
KeyString02: "leverandør"
KeyString03: "prosjektleder"
KeyString04: "prosjektnavn"
KeyString05: "tekniskPL"
KeyString06: "klasse"
KeyString07: "type"
KeyString08: "statusBeskrivelse"
KeyString09: "id"
LabelBinary00: null
LabelBinary01: null
LabelBinary02: null
LabelBinary03: null
LabelBinary04: null
LabelBoolean00: "Ekstern Deling"
LabelBoolean01: null
LabelBoolean02: null
LabelBoolean03: null
LabelBoolean04: null
LabelDateTime00: "Startdato"
LabelDateTime01: "Sluttdato"
LabelDateTime02: null
LabelDateTime03: null
LabelDateTime04: null
LabelInteger00: "Verdi"
LabelInteger01: null
LabelInteger02: null
LabelInteger03: null
LabelInteger04: null
LabelString00: "Prosjektstatus"
LabelString01: "Beskrivelse"
LabelString02: "Leverandør"
LabelString03: "Prosjektleder / KAM"
LabelString04: "Prosjektnavn"
LabelString05: "Teknisk PL"
LabelString06: "Prosjektklasse"
LabelString07: "Prosjekttype"
LabelString08: "Prosjesktstatus beskrivelse"
LabelString09: "Prosjekt"
ValueBinary00: null
ValueBinary01: null
ValueBinary02: null
ValueBinary03: null
ValueBinary04: null
ValueBoolean00: false
ValueBoolean01: null
ValueBoolean02: null
ValueBoolean03: null
ValueBoolean04: null
ValueDateTime00: "2020-01-07T00:00:00Z"
ValueDateTime01: "2021-02-10T00:00:00Z"
ValueDateTime02: null
ValueDateTime03: null
ValueDateTime04: null
ValueInteger00: 10000000
ValueInteger01: null
ValueInteger02: null
ValueInteger03: null
ValueInteger04: null
ValueString00: "Godkjennt"
ValueString01: "Dette prosjektet skal kjøpe inn."
ValueString02: "Siemens"
ValueString03: "Tom Tommerson"
ValueString04: "Innkjøp av nye leker"
ValueString05: "Adele Adelerson"
ValueString06: "Stort prosjekt"
ValueString07: "Innkjøp"
ValueString08: "En beskrivelse om status"
ValueString09: "20-12"
```

what i need to do is to create an array of objects where all the values that correspond are put together as such.

```
[
{
KeyBoolean00: "deling",
LabelBoolean00: "Ekstern Deling",
ValueBoolean00: false
},
{
KeyDateTime00: "start",
LabelDateTime00: "Startdato",
ValueDateTime00: "2020-01-07T00:00:00Z"
},
{
KeyString00: "status"
LabelString00: "Prosjektstatus"
ValueString00: "Godkjennt"
}
]
```

if that makes any sense.
I have tried some things, but im not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 3):

Use [substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) to get key number as `00`, `01`, ... and [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to build the necessary object

```js
const obj = {
    KeyBinary00: null,
    KeyBinary01: null,
    KeyBinary02: null,
    KeyBinary03: null,
    KeyBinary04: null,
    KeyBoolean00: 'deling',
    KeyBoolean01: null,
    KeyBoolean02: null,
    KeyBoolean03: null,
    KeyBoolean04: null,
    KeyDateTime00: 'start',
    KeyDateTime01: 'slutt',
    KeyDateTime02: null,
    KeyDateTime03: null,
    KeyDateTime04: null,
    KeyInteger00: 'verdi',
    KeyInteger01: null,
    KeyInteger02: null,
    KeyInteger03: null,
    KeyInteger04: null,
    KeyString00: 'status',
    KeyString01: 'beskrivelse',
    KeyString02: 'leverandør',
    KeyString03: 'prosjektleder',
    KeyString04: 'prosjektnavn',
    KeyString05: 'tekniskPL',
    KeyString06: 'klasse',
    KeyString07: 'type',
    KeyString08: 'statusBeskrivelse',
    KeyString09: 'id',
    LabelBinary00: null,
    LabelBinary01: null,
    LabelBinary02: null,
    LabelBinary03: null,
    LabelBinary04: null,
    LabelBoolean00: 'Ekstern Deling',
    LabelBoolean01: null,
    LabelBoolean02: null,
    LabelBoolean03: null,
    LabelBoolean04: null,
    LabelDateTime00: 'Startdato',
    LabelDateTime01: 'Sluttdato',
    LabelDateTime02: null,
    LabelDateTime03: null,
    LabelDateTime04: null,
    LabelInteger00: 'Verdi',
    LabelInteger01: null,
    LabelInteger02: null,
    LabelInteger03: null,
    LabelInteger04: null,
    LabelString00: 'Prosjektstatus',
    LabelString01: 'Beskrivelse',
    LabelString02: 'Leverandør',
    LabelString03: 'Prosjektleder / KAM',
    LabelString04: 'Prosjektnavn',
    LabelString05: 'Teknisk PL',
    LabelString06: 'Prosjektklasse',
    LabelString07: 'Prosjekttype',
    LabelString08: 'Prosjesktstatus beskrivelse',
    LabelString09: 'Prosjekt',
    ValueBinary00: null,
    ValueBinary01: null,
    ValueBinary02: null,
    ValueBinary03: null,
    ValueBinary04: null,
    ValueBoolean00: false,
    ValueBoolean01: null,
    ValueBoolean02: null,
    ValueBoolean03: null,
    ValueBoolean04: null,
    ValueDateTime00: '2020-01-07T00:00:00Z',
    ValueDateTime01: '2021-02-10T00:00:00Z',
    ValueDateTime02: null,
    ValueDateTime03: null,
    ValueDateTime04: null,
    ValueInteger00: 10000000,
    ValueInteger01: null,
    ValueInteger02: null,
    ValueInteger03: null,
    ValueInteger04: null,
    ValueString00: 'Godkjennt',
    ValueString01: 'Dette prosjektet skal kjøpe inn.',
    ValueString02: 'Siemens',
    ValueString03: 'Tom Tommerson',
    ValueString04: 'Innkjøp av nye leker',
    ValueString05: 'Adele Adelerson',
    ValueString06: 'Stort prosjekt',
    ValueString07: 'Innkjøp',
    ValueString08: 'En beskrivelse om status',
    ValueString09: '20-12',
};

const result = Object.values(
    Object.keys(obj).reduce((acc, key) => {
        const number = key.substring(key.length - 2, key.length); // 00

        acc[number] = acc[number] ? { ...acc[number], [key]: obj[key] } : { [key]: obj[key] };

        return acc;
    }, {}),
);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Almost got it. it now splits them up based on the numbers at the end. i wanna group them on two factors, the numbers at the end and the Data type in the name. like so 

`[{
KeyBinary04: null,
LabelBinary04: null,
ValueBinary04: null,
},{
KeyBoolean04: null,
LabelBoolean04: null,
ValueBoolean04: null
}, {
KeyString04: "prosjektnavn",
LabelString04: "Prosjektnavn",
ValueString04: "Innkjøp"
}, etc
]`

Comment: I think you can further customize this example for yourself, for example by adding in key `number` another `subsctring` or `regular expression`

Comment: Yeah that was what im working on now. Thanks again.